# Foggy effect pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, blur

Is it possible to blur (create blur filter) objects with pure javascript?
No CSS blur filter!

```
<div class="fog">
bla bla bla 
</div>

or

<div class="fog">
<img scr="link">
```

Hope somebody can help me :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using blur.js to achieve Gaussian blur effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592009/using-blur-js-to-achieve-gaussian-blur-effect)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** take a look at this http://blurjs.com/

You can create a blur-effect by placing multiple instances of sth. on top of each other. low opacity and slightly displaced and you have a blur-effect.

Or you render it to a canvas.

- Either the same way; drawing a node multiple times with low opacity and slightly displaced.
- Or by applying a ConvolutionFilter.
  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/

Comment: Thanks but is there a good example to learn canvas blur or can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Extended the answer, take a look at the linked library